# Dynamic input widgets in matrix form in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, lapply

I have developed a application using shiny which allow user to input number of rows and columns of his choice and then it will display accordingly that many number of input widgets accordingly in main panel. Currently with 1 column and as many rows it’s working.

My challenge is to replicate the same if user selects more than 1 column and those new columns should be adjacent to existing widgets in main panel in matrix form.

How to do that?

My code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel(title = "Adding input widgets horizontally and dynamically"), 
  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(numericInput("rows","Input No. of rows",value = 5),
                 br(),
                 numericInput("col","input No of col",value = 1)),

    mainPanel(uiOutput("plo"))
  )
)
)

server <- function(input,output){

  output$plo <- renderUI({

    lapply(seq(input$rows),function(i){
      numericInput(inputId = paste0("range",i),label = "col1",value = i)  
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that in a very similar fashion, use another `lapply` to wrap the inner `lapply` with a `column`. Try the following:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel(title = "Adding input widgets horizontally and dynamically"), 
  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(numericInput("rows","Input No. of rows",value = 5,min=1),
                 br(),
                 numericInput("col","input No of col",value = 1,min=1)),

    mainPanel(uiOutput("plo"))
  )
)
)

server <- function(input,output){

  output$plo <- renderUI({

    lapply(seq(input$col), function(j){
      column(width=3,
      lapply(seq(input$rows),function(i){
        numericInput(inputId = paste0("range",i,"_",j),label = "col1",value = i)  
      })
      )
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @ Florian Indeed it helped.Thanks. One small follow up ...how to access those values input by user?  for e.g  i want to show those values in min panel in form of a matrix

Comment: Hi @joy_1379, you can access them with input[[x]], where xis the name of the variable, created as `paste0("range",i,"_",j)`. To store them in a matrix, tou could create a reactive with the same `lapply` structure to collect the variables in lists and then `rbind` them for example. If you need more help with this, please consider posting this as a new question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Hi @Florian, I have posted this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48404848/update-matrix-values-in-shiny-using-numeric-input   Please have a look